# Unable to enable "Appear Offline" in Microsoft Lync 2010

Tags: lync-2010, lync-server-2010

I am unable to enable the Appear offline option in Microsfot Lync 2010 using Regedit and I have followed the following path but unable to find the "Communicator" folder in the below path and I unable to attached the error screenshot along with this question since I have less than 10 reputation and please find the below URL for the image.

http://picthost.net/image.php?di=WSQU

I even tried re-installing the software but still unable to find the above mentioned folder.

Please guide me to enable the folder and let me know if there is any other details required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried path below:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Software, Policies, Microsoft, Communicator

Comment: Guys any idea on this?

Answer (score -1):

1º Open Regedit

2º HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Communicator" /V "EnableAppearOffline" /D 1 /T REG_DWORD /F